# When to use –ing form and -ed form?

Tags: gerunds, past-participles, present-participles

I have read a manual. One of its sentences is "These are the basic symbols used generally."

I don't really understand the difference between

> These are the basic symbols **used** generally.

and

> These are the basic symbols **using** generally.

Can you provide some guidance on when I should use the –ing form instead of the -ed form?

Comment: The second sentence is not Standard English, and not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Only the first is possible here.

-ed is used for the verbs in the passive voice. Also look for "past participle."

-ing forms are used for the verbs in the continuous aspect. Also look for "ing-form," "present participle," "gerund."

Any grammar worth its salt:-) will show you the difference. Try this [this grammar forum](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/frm/f/340600179) and this [grammar site](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Both *-ed* and *-ing* words can be used as modifiers in addition to other parts of speech (typically they are or are involved in verbs).

As modifiers, the *-ing* form is appropriate if you want describe a state that could be described by saying "in the process of now" or "currently":

> The boiling water is hot.  (The water is in the process of boiling now, the water is currently boiling).
>
> The working men went to lunch.  (The men are currently working.)

The *-ed* form is appropriate if something has reached a destination state and is not undergoing any change, or has been transformed by an action.

> The boiled eggs tasted good.  (The eggs aren't being boiled now.)
>
> The destroyed building was reduced to rubble. (The building isn't being destroyed any more.)

It does *not* mean the action of the word has been completed by the subject of the sentence.  You need to use a verb or actual modifier for that.

> The worked men came home.  (Someone hearing this would immediately ask "men worked by who?")
>
> The men stopped working and came home.